# Is there a way to alert/popup in a rails controller method without rendering any other js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def delete_users
  users = User.active.where(:id=>params[:users])
  users.each do |user|
    array = []
    if user.active?
      array << user
    end
  end
  if (array.count > 0)
    user.update_attributes(:status => "inactive")
  else
    "I want an alert/popup here saying no users, when 'delete_users' is called and the condition comes here."
    ........ do other stuff ......
  end  

end
```

end

In a controller, I have this method, the ajax call will be made to get to this method and when the condition comes to else, I need an alert/popup saying no users are there to delete, then I can update some other thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put in else block  `return render :text => "no users are there to delete"`

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your `else` block:

```
render html: "<script>alert('No users!')</script>".html_safe
```

Note that if you want to include the `<script>` tag in a proper HTML layout (with a `<head>` tag, etc.), you'll need to explicitly specify a layout:

```
render(
  html: "<script>alert('No users!')</script>".html_safe,
  layout: 'application'
)
```

**Edit:**

Here's a little more code:

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def delete_users
    users = User.active.where(:id=>params[:users])
    array = []
    users.each do |user|
      if user.active?
        array << user
      end
    end
    if (array.count > 0)
      user.update_attributes(:status => "inactive")
    else
      render(
        html: "<script>alert('No users!')</script>".html_safe,
        layout: 'application'
      )
    end
  end
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # for the sake of example, simply have User.active return no users
  def self.active
    none
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # simply visit localhost:3000 to hit this action
  root 'users#delete_users'
end
```

Comment: tried but didn't work. I think it should be rendered back to a template to get it work.

Comment: What doesn't work? This works for me. I added some additional code in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't invoke a dialogue / popup box directly from the controller; it has to form part of a *response* to your browser.

---

Because Rails is built on the [HTTP stateless protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-say-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol), each *request* has to be met with a *response*. Unlike `TCP` or `Web Sockets`, HTTP only has the capacity to receive [ad-hoc responses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Technical_overview):

> HTTP functions as a request-response protocol in the client-server computing model. A web browser, for example, may be the client and an application running on a computer hosting a web site may be the server. The client submits an HTTP request message to the server. The server, which provides resources such as HTML files and other content, or performs other functions on behalf of the client, returns a response message to the client. The response contains completion status information about the request and may also contain requested content in its message body.

This means that you have deliver any front-end changes **to your browser** before they'll take effect (IE you can't just say "load dialogue" because it won't be sent to the browser):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, only: :destroy_users #-> this will invoke destroy_users.js.erb

   def destroy_users
      @users = User.active.where(id: params[:users]).count
      if @users.count > 0
         @users.update_all(status: "inactive")
      else
         @message = "No users......"
      end
   end
end

#app/views/your_controller/destroy_users.js.erb
<% if @message %>
  alert(<%=j @message %>);
<% end %>
```

The above code invokes the `js.erb` response which can be invoked using [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)

Comment: Can't we even display the flash messages in the middle of a controller Action?

Comment: Definitely not. You have to send the response back to the server