# what to write in callback url file in dibs payment?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, callbackurl, dibs, createdibsection

I have used a redirect method of payment using PHP. Can any one help with the callback file content?

I don't know what to define in `callback.php` file. 
I can't find any help from any source. 
I have already refereed below link about callback in dibs
http://tech.dibspayment.com/DX/Hosted/Output_parameters/Return_pages

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that `callbackUrl` is a parameter which same as others `cancelReturnUrl` and `acceptReturnUrl` parameters. Short description from your references

***acceptReturnUrl***

> Upon returning to acceptReturnUrl, the customer will normally expect a
>   receipt to be displayed.

***cancelReturnUrl***

> In case the customer cancels the purchase using the functionality in
>   the payment window (not by closing the window), he is returned to the
>   cancelReturnUrl

***callbackUrl***

> When the customer finishes a payment, he is redirected to the
>   acceptReturnUrl along with the return parameters. If the customer
>   stops the communication (closes the browser, loses internet connection
>   ect.) before reaching the webshop, the shop system is not informed of
>   the result of the purchase. To avoid this situation, an automatic
>   server-to-server call can be sent to the shop backend, enabled by
>   sending along the "callbackUrl" parameter. This URL is then
>   automatically called with the return parameters when the purchase is
>   accepted.
>
> The call is created as a post. All the previously described return
>   parameters are returned to the callbackUrl, and it accepts only port
>   80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS ) and 20080.

Because [http is a stateless protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-say-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol)  which means that the connection between the browser and the server is lost once the transaction ends. To solve this problem your payment gateway(DIBS) suggest to use `callbackUrl` parameter, give an url to this parameter which is listened at your side. If any problem occur like mentioned in the case (closes the browser, loses internet connection ect.) DIBS will return this url address which mentioned at your `callbackUrl` parameter with payment return parameters.

So at backend you can update your payment information.