# i want to change button color and text onclick and it should not change when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to change button colour and text on on click and it should not change when page is refreshed.Here when set status is clicked it changes the text to confirmed and colour changes to green,when i again click on it,it changes the colour to red and text changes to pending.Now when i again click on it,it should change the colour to green and text should change to confirmed,here neither the color changes nor the text is changed.And this should stay when page is refreshed.
here is the code:

```
<input type="submit" id="<?php echo $orderQuery['id'];?>" value="set status" onclick="setColor('<?php echo $orderQuery['id'];?>')"; />
<script>

var count = 1;

function setColor(btn) {
var property = document.getElementById(btn);

if (count == 0) {property.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"
 if (property.value=="confirmed") property.value = "pending";
 }
 else {property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
 count = 0;
if (property.value=="set status") property.value = "confirmed";
}

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You may set a user cookie if you want this change to persist between the page refreshes for this particular user. However, if they view the same page from another browser (or from another PC), it won't have any effect. You should carefully consider what exactly you need this for, and what would the consequences be if you choose this approach.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP is Stateless Protocol**
we cannot maintain the state between HTTP Calls
for more info [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-say-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol)

So you have to save the data that you need next time (In your case button color) by other mechanism like **Query Strings,Cookies or Sessions**

**QUERY STRINGS**

you can use query string to carry the information that you want to preserve
like

```
www.example.com?btnColor=blue
```

and ofcourse at the page loading you can set the color with php something like this.

```
//pseudo code
if(isset($_GET['btnColor']) // for query string
 echo  '<button style="background:'.$_GET['btnColor'].'">'
if(isset($_COOKIE['btnColor']) // for cookie
 echo  '<button style="background:'.$_COOKIE['btnColor'].'">'
if(isset($_SESSION['btnColor']) // for Session based storage
 echo  '<button style="background:'.$_SESSION['btnColor'].'">'
```

**COOKIES & SESSIONS**

you can also use the cookies to save your btn color

```
setcookie("color", "red", time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
// and you can retrieve the cookie value from


 echo $_COOKIE['color'] // prints red
```

The sessions can be used in following way

```
//to set the session
$_SESSION['color'] = "red";
// to retrive the data
echo $_SESSION['color'];
```

The major advantage of cookie and sessions are they save the information over a period
For more information and detailed information  please look at php.net documentation.

Comment: yes i want to maintain the button color when the page is refreshed

Comment: What siddhesh said is true, you should send what you want to keep via the url, however there is another way you could do this... it is called localstorage. I am not sure about the browser support but I know Chrome can do it. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp