# Why is HTTP called a stateless protocol even when it can send state information in its Cookie header?

Tags: http, stateless

I am really confused as to why HTTP is called a stateless protocol when it has the provisions to send the state information, like for example cookies of in any other HTTP headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it said that "HTTP is a stateless protocol"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-is-it-said-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol):

> [...]a stateless protocol is a communications protocol in which no session information is retained by the receiver, usually a server. Relevant session data is sent to the receiver by the client in such a way that every packet of information transferred can be understood in isolation, without context information from previous packets in the session.

Cookies are sent with *every* request.

Besides, often cookies contain not the state itself, but only the `id` of a session which stores the state.