# Where does IIS store user created sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, session-variables

From this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5892/Session-Management-in-ASP-NET i have understood that session is stored in a browser in cookie (lets just assume Cookieless=false) and how it is used for future communication to overcome stateless nature of the web.I have one doubt - Where are sessions created by code (e.g. Session["abc"]="test data") stored? Are they only stored on server or they are also stored in cookies(which is highly unlikely)?If they are stored on server,where are they stored? How are the sessions created through code identified for one particular user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does IIS recognize different sessions in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521311/how-does-iis-recognize-different-sessions-in-net)

Comment: Thanks Black frog. But i have already gone through that. Doesn't explain how code created sessions are handled by IIS.Or maybe i have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session["abc"]="test data"  is Stored in RAM by default as for ASP.net`

Two different Facebook users when request "www.facebook.com/home" both are sent different pages ,eg user1 will have his profile news ,user2 will have different profile.

So what's the flow-->

- user1 logs in www.abc.com .
- Server saves sessionid `darw12sxa3towkoiuhztcf0c` as cookies in user1 browser.
- Server Maps `darw12sxa3towkoiuhztcf0c` to user1 in its memory.
- Next all the user1 url requests will have this sessionid ,so server can identify `darw12sxa3towkoiuhztcf0c` is mapped to user1 and serves pages corresponding to him.
- user2 when logs in www.abc.com is assigned a different sessionid say `pvsc5msqma5nrusmdnn2y13n`...so on.

Some INFO

- Corrsponding to this sessionid all Session data is stored in RAM by default for Asp.Net.Website Admin can change it  to other means.
- Sessionid is stored as cookies corresponding to domain name.
- These Sessionid is transfered over network for each web request ,so it is vunerable to attacks as man in middle can use these sessionid,So one of the reason why HTTPS comes into picture and saves the day.

Try using  [Edit this Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) Chrome Extension ,to view and copy cookies from one computer to another computer.

Have Fun.